# My SPA does not load in AngularJS using Routing

Tags: angularjs, view, angularjs-scope, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I have just started getting into AngularJS and was following the guide [AngularJS in 60 Minutes](http://fastandfluid.com/publicdownloads/AngularJSIn60MinutesIsh_DanWahlin_May2013.pdf) by Dan Wahlin up to page 79. However, I’m only presented with my homepage which is blank by default; it does not load my view1.html which it should, according to the guide. I’ve been trying to locate the problem but cannot find it.

Unlike this guide, though, I’m not running the program through localhost but through file:///Users/.../home.html.

My code so far in home.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
<head>
<title>Lekstuga</title>
</head>


<!-- _________________________________( Home )_________________________________ -->

<body>
<div>
    <div data-ng-view></div>   //here it should load Partials/view1.html
</div>


<!-- _________________________________( Scripts )________________________________  -->

<script src="AngularJSDemos/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', []);

demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',
    {
        controller: 'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
    })
    .when('/view2',
    {
        controller:'SimpleController',
        templateUrl: 'Partials/View2.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/view1' });
});

demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
    {name: 'Kalle Anka', city:'Duckville'}, 
    {name: 'Pelle Andersson', city: 'Pelletown'},
    {name: 'Pelle Eriksson', city:'Pelletown'}, 
    {name: 'Kajsa Larsson', city: 'Kajskroga'}
    ];
    $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        $scope.customers.push(
            { 
                name: $scope.newCustomer.name,
                city: $scope.newCustomer.city
            });
    };      
});



demoApp.controller('SimpleController', SimpleController);

</script>       


<!-- _________________________________( END )_________________________________ -->  

</body>
</html>
```

Followed by my code in View1.html:

```
<div class = "container">
<h2>View 1</h2>
Name:
<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name" />
<br />
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:'city' | filter:filter.name">
    {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city | uppercase }}</li>
</ul>

<br />
Customer Name:<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.name" />
<br />
Customer City:<br />
<input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.city" />
<br />
<button data-ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button><br />
<a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
templateUrl: 'Partials/View1.html'
```

Angular looks in the same place where your index.html is. You probably have placed 'Partials' folder in app/views or something like that. Just provide the full path relative to the folder where 'index.html' is located.

But in general – may I suggest you to run a local webserver with nginx or MAMP or just use Yeoman http://yeoman.io/. This will make your life much easier.

Comment: I tried moving view1.html to the same folder as home.html and changing to templateUrl: 'View1.html', templateUrl: '/View1.html' .. I think theres wrong somewhere else in the code?

Comment: BTW, you have redirectTo: '/view1', but no route with '/view1' actually, you only have / and /view2.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change as of version 1.2 : the routing functionality has been moduled out.

The fix however is simple enough :

1. Load the new javascriptfile in your code : `<script src=".yourjs/angular-route.js"></script>`    You can download it here http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/  (other versions other paths of course)
2. Indicate the  `'ngRoute'` dependency in your code : `var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);`